# Increment operation behaviour on signed char in C

Tags: c

For signed char in C, the range is from -128 to 127. How can `a+1` (as in the code), produce 128 and not -128? The subsequent increment is normal (-127 for both `a` and `i`).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char i=127,a=127;
    printf("%d\n",++i);//output is -128
    printf("%d\n",a+1);//output is 128
    //subsequent increment after this is -127 for a and i.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1` is `int`, so `a+1` is `int` passed as `int`. The result of `a+1` is not assigned to `char` at any point.

Comment: so is a impliciltly converted to int when 1 is encountered? @Weather Vane

Comment: Please see the answer from @AnT.

Comment: Yes.noted @WeatherVane

Comment: As a side note, `char` is not necessarily signed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When used with arithmetic operators, all small integer types (`bool`, `char`, `short`) are subjected to *integer promotions* before any arithmetic is perfomed on them. In the `a + 1` expression your `a` is promoted to `int` meaning that this expression is actually interpreted as `(int) a + 1`. The range of `char` plays no role here. All calculations are performed in the domain of `int` and the result has `int` type. `127 + 1` is `128`, which is what you see printed.

Your `++i` is defined as `i = i + 1`. For the same reasons the right-hand side is calculated as `(int) i + 1`, meaning that in this case the addition is performed in the domain of `int` as well. Later the result is converted back to `char` and stored back into `i`. The addition itself does not overflow and produces `128`, but the subsequent conversion back to `char` "overflows", which produces *implementation-defined behavior*. In your case that implementation-defined behavior produced the value of `-128` as `char` result.

Comment: Just for completeness the `%d` format in `printf("%d\n",++i);` then works because the `char` is then promoted back to an `int` as a default promotion in the variadic argument rules!

Comment: @AnT, citing to what you said, I have a doubt in (a+1).                               "All calculations are performed in the domain of int and the result has int type. 127 + 1 is 128, which is what you see printed." I am convinced of this;but consider next increment of a=128.(a+1 again).The output prints as -127; not 129, as you consider should happen for a.

Comment: @Shivani: This fails at the very beginning. `a=128` is already out of range with implementation-defined behavior. In your implementation `a = 128` is equivalent to `a = -128`. Only after that `a + 1` is calculated as I described above and expectedly produces `-127` result.